# Framelayout different heights

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, android-framelayout

I have a Activity conainting a header with some buttons(See picture).

You can switch the framelayout by clicking on the buttons. I have the framelayout set on wrap_content in the height for making the whole thing scrollable in a scrollview.

But I want to show only a map in the framelayout if you push on button2. And the height of the map need to be FILL_PARENT INSTEAD of WRAP_CONTENT. So I need to change the heigth of the FRAMELAYOUT.

Any ideas how I can do that?

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;//MATCH_PARENT because FILL_PARENT is deprectated
                frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```